# Word for a yes/no question that's more to elicit a longer response

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word or idiomatic phrase to describe a question that can be answered by a "yes" or "no", but has a higher probability of getting a more open-ended response.

Indeed, without the "yes/no" requirement I'd describe what I'm looking for as an "open ended question", but the possibility to answer "yes/no" is key here.

An example question would be:

> Do you feel remorse for your affiliations with the Nazi party?

Although it doesn't have to be a loaded question, just something which you are reasonably sure is going to get the responder talking beyond the y/n

Comment: If you find no particular word or phrase you could as well be explicit and ask for the answerer to *at least* say yes or no.

Comment: do you have an example question?

Comment: @N.N. I'm asking how to describe a question that would elicit a more open-ended response even thought it could be answered y/n...not how to get someone to answer y/n

Comment: If we buy into Wikipedia's contrast between [open-ended and closed-ended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-ended_question) questions, I guess OP is thinking of a *middle-ended question*. But that's [not currently a recognised term](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&source=hp&q=%22middle-ended+question%22&pbx=1&oq=%22middle-ended+question%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=230406l236750l1l237250l21l20l0l0l0l5l203l2561l9.9.2l20l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b82765d88c56fc8f&biw=1138&bih=846).

Comment: Guess it depends who you're asking.

Comment: @Matt "Do you feel remorse for your affiliations with the Nazi party?"...although it doesn't have to be a loaded question, just something which you are reasonably sure is going to get the responder talking beyond the y/n

Comment: @FumbleFingers middle-ended question is really a perfect description, might have to just make up a word.  Essentially its an open-ended question disguised as a close-ended question.

Comment: @pedantic: Feel free to post *middle-ended* as the answer to your own question. That way you can be sure it'll get at least one upvote (mine!).

Comment: **WOW!** I just created my very own [Googlewhack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlewhack) there! Assuming [TPTB](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=TPTB) will accept hyphenated "middle-ended" as a single word, paired with "question".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hahaha, that makes it all worthwhile!  Also if someone puts middle-ended down for the answer I'll accept it, even though its part of SE culture I can't bring myself to answer my own question.

Answer (score 3):

**Exam question** came to my mind, just for fun though.

A typical exam question:

> Is hell exothermic or endothermic?

How would we answer that? Should we just respond with *exothermic* or *endothermic* without a tedious justification, we simply wouldn't expect to get the mark.

Check out [one possible open-ended answer](http://thekruser.com/2010/06/08/is-hell-exothermic-or-endothermic-a-brilliant-theory/) for a laugh.

Answer (score 2):

Your example looks like a *leading question*, where an alert answerer will argue with the framing of the question rather than simply giving a yes/no answer (and the lawyer who asked it will yell "Just answer yes or no, please!" while the opposing lawyer calls for an objection).

Answer (score 0):

'Surface probe'-a question asked to elicit a reaction rather than a specific answer. I've got no authority for this definition, other than its use by S.J. Perelman in one of his 'feuilletons'